# Hash Table -implement a dictionary by using direct addressing on a huge array

Tags: dictionary, hashtable

To implement a dictionary by using direct addressing on a huge array. At
the start, the array entries may contain garbage, and initializing the entire array
is impractical because of its size.so here's the question is how to check whether a data entry is valid or not !!

Answer (score 0):

We can use validating cycle to implement such direct addressing hash table 
we've to maintain an auxiliary array implemented somewhat like a stack whose size is equal to the number of valid entries in the hash table...
hash table T
Arrays S and S' size equal to valid entries 
Insert operation- to insert an object x with key k put T[k]=j , j is top[S] the index of auxiliary array S and put the key k at jth S[j]=k and to store pointer to the object put S'[k]=pointer to the object

to search - if(S[T[k]]==T[k] ) validate the cycle 
insert,search,delete  operations take O(1).